# Scanner(line) and Scanner(System.in) misbehaving / human error

Tags: java, eclipse, line

Solved, but I've too low reputation to answer my own Q yet.

Scanner input;
    Scanner lineScanner;

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
String line;
char x;

askUserForInputFile();   //user selects input txt file. Method definitely works.

do {
    line = input.nextLine();
    if (line.length() < 6)
        continue;
        out.printf("debug0\n%s", line);   //<----problem

    do {
        out.print("debug1\n");
        x = lineScanner.next().charAt(0);   //<-----problem
        out.print("debug2\n");

//more code
```

I want to read line by line from a file and process it only if its length() => 6. What's wrong?

console:

```
  debug0
  Exception in thread "main" <scanned line, displayed correctly>debug
  java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? line: `lineScanner = new Scanner(line);` - where is `line` defined?

Comment: Maybe you need a file object

Comment: I have found the solution, I needed to declare String line before using line.next(). Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `lineScanner` at the beginning of each iteration with `lineScanner = new Scanner(line);`. It is currently trying to read in from your first line every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this

```
public static File askUserForInputFile() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
    String filename = input.nextLine();

    return new File(fileName);
}
```

Use the method here

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = askUserForInputFile();

input = new Scanner(file);

Scanner lineScanner;
String line;
char x;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();

    if (line.length() < 6)
        out.printf("debug0\n%s", line);
    else {
        out.print("debug1\n");
        x = lineScanner.next().charAt(0);   //<-----problem
        out.print("debug2\n");
    }  
}
```